# How to integrate Spring with Drools-6.2.0.Final version

Tags: drools

I will integration Drools 6.2.0 with Spring.I don't know what to do. Who can give me a example?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I wrote a little blog (with a linked GitHub repo) about doing this here: http://scattercode.co.uk/2015/02/06/a-minimal-spring-boot-drools-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below url which explains integrating Spring with Drools 5:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-drools5/

Then migrate from Drools 5 to 6 by referring:
[Migrating Spring drools-context.xml from 5.0 to 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762849/migrating-spring-drools-context-xml-from-5-0-to-6-0/28828717#28828717)